# ViewPager's slow swiping issue

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager

In my android application I have 6 fragments. I am doing some XML parsing and populating listviews. Swiping first time is slow, then it works fine. But when I wait some minutes or I close app and reopen it after some operations with other apps, the fragments changes slow first time, then again swipe works well. I use ViewPager and also I set         mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5), but it isn't solve the problem.
What can I else do for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?